# 404 FILE NOT FOUND: After Restoring Content DB

Tags: content-database, restore, iis, 404

I have taken backup of content DB of one web application from production database server and restored to my development database server. content DB restored successfully. Content DBs have exactly same Names and scheme info in both production and in development and are connected to same web application name in both environments. I just take back up from production db because of more content in production. but when i tried to view the app in browser i got this: 404 FILE NOT FOUND.
Then I reset IIS and browse the site from IIS Manager, I got this:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Date: Fri, 08 Apr 2016 13:21:36 GMT
Connection: close

Then I see from central admin, that content DB was not attached to existing Web app. I tried to attached db to existing web app, then i got this error:

"This content database has a schema version which is not supported in this farm"

My app was working fine in development environment before content DB restore.

Whats the problem?

Comment: App, as in list or as developed app?

Comment: App means  Web Application that was already created and was woring fine. But after content DB restore, it that error

Comment: So you attached a second content database to the web application in your development environment? Could it be that you have two root site collection for the same webapplication? One in each content database?

Comment: I tried to attach same content DB after restoring with same content DB name, But I got this error:  "This content database has a schema version which is not supported in this farm" Any idea to fix it? I have updated my question

Comment: Sounds like you have tried to restore with a database that were with an older patch version. Correct?

Comment: I have no idea about patch version, whats is that? I just take backup from Production DB and restored to development DB. Then I go to central admin and click "add content database" with correct web app selected. And i see this error: "This content database has a schema version which is not supported in this farm". Any idea to fix?

Comment: Patch version/build number would be what current versionyour SharePoint farm is running on. Say that one farm is running version 10.1 and the other farm is running 10.2 then you can't move a database between them as they are running on different versions. Do you know how to use PowerShell?

Comment: If your production enviroment is on a newer patchlevel, you will have to patch your dev environment to the same patch level as your production to attach the database. If your development environment is on a newer patch level, then you need to patch your production to the same patch level and backup the content db again.

Comment: Now, I understand !!, By using Powershell, we can get build number of our Farm (get-spfarm).buildversion. That needs to be same on both environment, Is that is the solution?

Comment: Yes! The schema in every database has the current build number so that's why it won't work. Fix that, and you should be able to move/take a new copy and attach it.